# How to close Twitter stream with Needle in Node?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm experimenting with the new Twitter v2 API and I'm using their example from GitHub in a node application. They use the npm module `needle` for their requests.

```
// Open a realtime stream of Tweets, filtered according to rules
// https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/quick-start

const needle = require('needle');

// The code below sets the bearer token from your environment variables
// To set environment variables on macOS or Linux, run the export command below from the terminal:
// export BEARER_TOKEN='YOUR-TOKEN'
const token = process.env.BEARER_TOKEN;

const rulesURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules';
const streamURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream';

// this sets up two rules - the value is the search terms to match on, and the tag is an identifier that
// will be applied to the Tweets return to show which rule they matched
// with a standard project with Basic Access, you can add up to 25 concurrent rules to your stream, and
// each rule can be up to 512 characters long

// Edit rules as desired below
const rules = [{
        'value': 'dog has:images -is:retweet',
        'tag': 'dog pictures'
    },
    {
        'value': 'cat has:images -grumpy',
        'tag': 'cat pictures'
    },
];

async function getAllRules() {

    const response = await needle('get', rulesURL, {
        headers: {
            "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })

    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        throw new Error(response.body);
    }

    return (response.body);
}

async function deleteAllRules(rules) {

    if (!Array.isArray(rules.data)) {
        return null;
    }

    const ids = rules.data.map(rule => rule.id);

    const data = {
        "delete": {
            "ids": ids
        }
    }

    const response = await needle('post', rulesURL, data, {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })

    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        throw new Error(response.body);
    }

    return (response.body);

}

async function setRules() {

    const data = {
        "add": rules
    }

    const response = await needle('post', rulesURL, data, {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })

    if (response.statusCode !== 201) {
        throw new Error(response.body);
    }

    return (response.body);

}

function streamConnect() {

    const stream = needle.get(streamURL, {
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "v2FilterStreamJS",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        timeout: 20000
    });

    stream.on('data', data => {
        try {
            const json = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(json);
        } catch (e) {
            // Keep alive signal received. Do nothing.
        }
    }).on('error', error => {
        if (error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
            stream.emit('timeout');
        }
    });

    return stream;

}


(async () => {
    let currentRules;

    try {
        // Gets the complete list of rules currently applied to the stream
        currentRules = await getAllRules();

        // Delete all rules. Comment the line below if you want to keep your existing rules.
        await deleteAllRules(currentRules);

        // Add rules to the stream. Comment the line below if you don't want to add new rules.
        await setRules();

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(-1);
    }

    // Listen to the stream.
    // This reconnection logic will attempt to reconnect when a disconnection is detected.
    // To avoid rate limits, this logic implements exponential backoff, so the wait time
    // will increase if the client cannot reconnect to the stream.

    const filteredStream = streamConnect();
    let timeout = 0;
    filteredStream.on('timeout', () => {
        // Reconnect on error
        console.warn('A connection error occurred. Reconnecting…');
        setTimeout(() => {
            timeout++;
            streamConnect();
        }, 2 ** timeout);
        streamConnect();
    })

})();
```

My question now is how can I close this stream. In my app I'm trying to manually stop and restart the stream when I need it. But during my testing I ran a couple of times into the maximum amount of open streams.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

The stream can be stopped by aborting the request,

```
stream.request.abort()
```

where *stream* is the variable found in the streamConnect() function

Comment: can I stop it after a number of req? For example after 5 requests